# App rejected. Eligibility issues from Google Play for Android TV

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

After Uploading Android TV application on play store google give me this error. But i already include tv-launcher image. Application is working fine on Xiaomi MI TV BOX. I also go through this [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/app-rejected-eligibility-issues-from-google-play-for-android-tv.536869/) but didn't find any solution.

> Hi Developers at MYAPP-TV,
>
> Thanks for submitting your app for Android
> TV. We reviewed MYAPP-TV, with package name com.xyz.myapp, and noticed
> some eligibility issues.
>
> App status: Your app has not been accepted
> into Android TV. This does not affect your app’s status on Google
> Play.
>
> Eligibility issues by APK version: Version(s) Eligibility Issue
>
> APK:4 Crashing After Launch.
> Your app crashes immediately after launch,
> which means we cannot review your app for Android TV inclusion. Please
> refer to our TV Activity documentation for details.
>
> APK:4  No full-size
> app banner Your app does not contain a full-size app banner or is it
> not visible in the launcher. We are targeting 1080P, which we consider
> xhdpi. Apps should include the banner in the xhdpi (320 dpi) drawables
> folder with a size of (320px × 180px). Please refer to our Home Screen
> Banner and UI Patterns documentation.
>
> The title should help users
> identify apps in the launcher. Please refer to our Visual Design and
> User Interaction documentation for more information.
>
> Next steps:
>
> 1. Make the necessary changes to your app.
> 2. Submit your app for another review. Or, if you’d like to exclude your app from Android TV:
> 3. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 4. Opt out of Android TV on the Pricing & Distribution page.
> 5. Click Submit update.
>
> For more details on how an app can qualify for Android TV, you can review the Android TV App Quality Guidelines. If
> you feel we have made this determination in error, please submit
> additional information to our team and we’ll review your app again.
>
> Thanks for supporting Google Play, The Google Play Team We'd
> appreciate your feedback on Android TV policy notifications. Help us
> improve the developer experience by completing this three question
> survey.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be a coding issue

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Any news about this 'Crashing after launch' issue?

Comment: @sgallego No, i still not find the solution

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two distinct issues:

1) that your app doesn't run on their test device. If it runs on your device, a rebuild might be sufficient, but I really cannot say.

2) your app is either missing a 320 x 180 banner, or that it doesn't contain the name of your app on it. That last part is important because their rejection reasons are particularly unclear about this.

Try including a new banner where the title of your app is clearly visible and submit again after fixing the crashing issue and see if that doesn't solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

After some application submits we have solved 'Crashing after launch issue'. In our case there was not a crash, but an error while trying to make an in-app purchase.

We fill the form from the link in the rejection email requesting more information:

> If you feel we have made this determination in error, please submit
>   additional information to our team and we'll review your app again.

and they shown us the error screen. Then, we only had to give their test user accesss as payments tester and we are now Android TV compliant !! : D

For the second issue, you only have to put to 320x180 banner into drawable-xhdpi directory. It will be your app icon in TV app.